# Inversion of incomplete elliptic integral of third kind

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, special-functions, elliptic-integrals

I would like to know whether there is any solution available on the inversion of elliptic integrals of the third kind (incomplete)?

That means that given $\Pi(n,u,m) = f(x)$, I would like to obtain $u$ as a function of $x$. Here, $m = (sin(\alpha))^2$ is the parameter and $n$ is the characteristic.

I know how to invert elliptic integrals of the first kind (incomplete), but I haven't been able to find anything useful in order to invert a general elliptic integral of the third kind (incomplete, non-circular case).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still interested, but here you go:

1. Write $f(x)=\Pi(n,u,m)$ as a series $f(x)=S(u)$ in $u$ around $u_0=0$.
2. Inverse/reverse that series $S(u)$ to the reverse series $T(v)$ with the property that $T(S(u))=u$. Then insert $f(x)$ into $T(v)$ to get a series representation $u=T(f(x))$ of $u$.

This can be done with help of a computer algebra system like Mathematica or Maple. 
A numerical approach is given here: [T. Fukushima: Numerical Inversion of General Incomplete Elliptic Integral](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/233758083_Numerical_Inversion_of_General_Incomplete_Elliptic_Integral)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but here is only the idea since using the [**Riemann Theta function**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SiegelTheta.html) is complicated. A rational expression of the function inverts an Abelian integral as introduced [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelianFunction.html):

$$\int \frac {dx}{\sqrt{\sum\limits_{n=0}^d a_nx^n}}\tag1$$

and [Ellipic Pi $\Pi(a,t,b)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+1%2F%28sqrt%281+-+x%5E2%29+%281+-+a+x%5E2%29+sqrt%281+-+b+x%5E2%29%29) has this integral representation in the Wolfram language:

$$\Pi(a,\sin^{-1}(x),b)=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1-ax^2)\sqrt{1-bx^2}}=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(2a+b+1)x^2+(a^2+2a+b)x^4-(a^2b+a^2+2ab)x^6+a^2bx^8}}$$

which fits the general form in $(1)$. Therefore, it is invertible in terms of the Riemann Theta function.

> [Inversion of hyperelliptic integrals of arbitrary genus with application to particle motion in general relativity](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0393044011000027?token=A57E10700B7EE460485A79629E6974FC49405FC01AA70CC584E392E7F2F3D0C26292B05AA50209F48F04FAA0E977709F&originRegion=us-east-1&originCreation=20220723024326)

shows how to use the function for the more advanced user.